# Jquery resize hides overflow scrollbar until browser resized

Tags: jquery, resize

The overflow is on the x axis and Im wanting the scroll bar to appear above a fixed footer of 60px. So the height is calculated and this works.

```
$('#shf').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=60px');
```

When i add the resize event it hides it on initial load but then appears once the browser is resized. 2 separate examples I've tried:

adding show event

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#shf').show();
    $('#shf').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=60px');
});
```

creating a resize function and calling this after

```
function resizePortfolioScroll(){
var $height = $('#shf').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=60px');
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#shf').show();
    resizePortfolioScroll();
});
```

How do I get the scroll bar to load upon initial loading of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding resize on initial load.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#shf').show();
    resizePortfolioScroll();
}).resize();
```